# How to re-render a component in reactis whenever we redirect to it or access it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering

In Reactjs I am redirecting to signup page using history and after signup again redirecting to home but how to re render the home page to show thae changes . I am storing cookie in browser after signup.

Comment: once u signup, u are landing on the home page. Then why u need to rerender again

Answer (score 0):

Use useeffect hook and give dependency as the item which u need to update

example

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if(props.data){
        //tasks here
    }
}, [props.data])
```

Comment: Any elaborate reference if possible?

Answer (score 0):

once u signup, u are landing on the home page. just store the cookie in the useState. When u changed the state value it will rerender the component

Comment: Okay but how would I change the state. What I mean is how to trigger a function when signup is done as I am using history I am not able to get it.   If you can provide any reference it will be very helpful.

Comment: @JoydeepDey Trigger a function in signup component or the home component? BTW why do you need to trigger a function if the page is redirected to home page. ?